# How to use capybara upload file?

Tags: capybara

the html like this
       `<input type='file' id='ok' class='lalalalala'>`

my code is
    attach_file("ok","./fileset/publisher/upload_pic.jpg")
but I got fail:
Failures:

```
 Capybara::ElementNotFound:
   Unable to find file field "ok"
```

so what is file field? 
how can I upload file?

Answer (score 24, accepted):

From the Capybara docs:

```
The file field can be found via its name, id or label text.
```

And you clearly have this already, which is a bit puzzling. Is there a modal window blocking this and/or is the page.driver switched to something else by chance? I ask because it's actually *not completely necessary* to interact with a form button and cause a modal or file/Explorer/Finder window to appear, and sometimes this can confuse the page.driver (ex: switches focus to the window instead of the page).

Try removing any click_button actions just prior to this step, and then try this:

```
attach_file('ok', File.absolute_path('./fileset/publisher/upload_pic.jpg'))
```

This has worked for me previously, in a super deeply parented div which ended up with a button class.